# Microsoft dynamics - which one to go for; ERP OR CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-ax-2009, erp

I have requirement of preparing an in-house Project Management and accounting app using Microsoft Dynamics. My requirements are similar to what explained in the below page:

http://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/f/117/p/54453/98182.aspx

Can someone suggest that should we use ERP or CRM? And which one to use i.e. SL, GP, NAV, AX? And why?

Answer (score 2):

CRM is probably the first choice to eliminate. Project management is usually an internally facing application, while CRM is by definition, externally facing. Secondly, if you need to maintain budgets, Dynamics CRM doesn't have anything built in for this (a general ledger for example).

As for the others, each will have its own costs and the extent of support you can get for any of them will vary depending on where your business is located. In some areas you may be able to get good SL support but no NAV or AX for example.

As for one you may not have considered, have you considered Project Server / SharePoint? If you need really heavy weight PM capability, Project may be your best bet. SharePoint can do some PM stuff. There's at least [one book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520144/) around by Dux Raymond Sy, published by O'Reilly. He's also done at least one [webcast](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/e/1283). Both are based on SharePoint 2007.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Of the Dynamics ERP products, SL is the one most focused on the project management (i.e. Project Accounting) space. CRM doesn't have a lot of project management capabilities built in, but is probably the most customisable and extendable of the dynamics range.

If you're after something that needs to cover the financial aspect of PM (e.g. billing, tracking costs etc) then you should look at the ERP options. If you're not worried about the financial side, then building a custom solution within CRM might be an option.

Answer (score 2):

Came across this thread in a search I was doing. Hope Sukhminder Singh is still listening...

Sounds like you shouldn't abandon Dynamics CRM, a tool which your organization has tried and tested for nurturing customer satisfaction and turning it into ongoing revenue. On the other hand, you need to maintain a smooth accounting and billing relationship with the same customers - and for that, you'll need an ERP solution. As ccellar suggested NAV can do that, or even SharePoint, as suggested by Mike. I'll hazard a guess your organization already has SharePoint, too.

Now, what about the integration? You know, devising an effective, scalable, and future-proof way for getting MS folk to "talk" is quite a challenge! Also, you need a solution that places stress on human, as well as system workflows. The human factor can be decisive in time-critical projects.

Sukhminder, are you going to be coding solutions on either end? That's one way to go, though often, that option comes with high overheads: dragged-out coding projects, functionality that can be difficult to maintain, and even harder to modify, and serious concerns when one of the systems is upgraded or replaced.

**From another angle--are you considering BPM**? I'd urge you to.

BPM (Business Process Management) software suites are becoming an increasingly practical and mainstream option as an organization's central integration hub. BPM lets you rapidly map out and control mission critical processes involving multiple systems (as in your scenario). BPM lets you visualize the players, processes and apps over time, and when it comes to adjusting, remapping, and remodeling your workflows, you may have to do some coding, but a large part of the work can be done by experienced, non-programmer BPM users.

There are a bunch of vendors out there, each with its own pros and cons. For the job of connecting MS CRM and MS ERP/Sharepoint, here are 3 candidates I have come across.

1. Kofax's TotalAgility BMP integrates between Dynamics CRM and SharePoint, by leveraging SharePoint capabilities. The solution obviates elaborate coding by supporting workflows, rules, and user screens. It "orchestrates" processes between itself and other MS and products, most notably SharePoint, CRM, Lync, Visio, Outlook. They enable "in-flight" process change and dynamic BPM, so that down-time on your production is minimal. See the [data sheet](http://www.kofax.com/downloads/datasheets/ds-kofax-totalagility-sharepoint-en.pdf).
2. Sequence [Business Process Management](http://www.pnmsoft.com) from PNMsoft. Provides integration with systems from many vendors. The forte is on human-centric processes, with a strong bent for Microsoft products. Sequence lets you integrate with existing systems using wizard-based connectors. When your organization changes, Sequence lets you "hot-swap" your business processes fast, without down time in your production.
3. MuleSoft's [CRM-ERP integration](http://www.mulesoft.com/resources/esb/crm-erp-integration). Their strong point is application integration, for connecting (legacy) systems from a range of vendors, including SAP, Oracle, Salesforce.com, and MS. The Mule ESB is a lightweight integration platform. It comes with a library of connectors to quickly create connectivity with all systems and services, whether on-premise or in the cloud. When adding or modifying an endpoint, you can easily update your integrations to reflect the change.

HTH some....

Answer (score 1):

I'd start off at the [Microsoft Dynamics site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/default.aspx) and explore what each product has on offer.  They even have an [ERP selector tool](http://www.microsoft.com/global/en-us/dynamics/RichMedia/erpSelector/ERPtoolStandAlone.html) for you to try out with just a few questions.  Why not [contact Microsoft yourself](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/contact-us.aspx) and they could provide a list of potential partners that work in your area - it will be an important decision and they would better guide you through the selection process.

Answer (score 1):

After a few projects which also had an accounting part, I would not recommend to use Dynamics CRM (at least for the accounting part). That's not what it's meant for and you have to spend much effort to get to a level of Dynamics NAV for example.

On the other side: why not combine both systems and use their strenghts.

Comment: Being specific for explaining requirements, I'll have clients, their contract (one for each), and multiple projects of each client and multiple milestones of each project. My requirement is to manage the billing/invoice of each milestone; basically the financial part of Project Management. Also, Our company is already  using Dynamics CRM for Marketing and Sales. My question is would it be a good idea to do customization with CRM OR to use ERP (probably SL in my case) as it's more project management oriented contrary to CRM which is more of Product Management.